# How to retrieve image in kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to retrieve image from the images folder of the firebase. However, Its show the "Failed to retrieve the image" meessage. May I know where have I do wrong ?

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_image"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_description"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        />

    val imageName = restaurant.imageName
    val imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images/$imageName.jpg")
    val localfile = File.createTempFile("TempImage","jpg")
    imageRef.getFile(localfile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localfile.absolutePath)
        binding.restaurantImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to retrieve the image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the Toast message inside addOnFailureListener show something?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes, because I cannot retrieve the image from the firebase so it will show the toast message. May I know how to retrieve the image successfully?

Comment: Have you tried to show the error?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have tried to comment out the addOnFailureListener, but did not display any error occured.

Comment: No, you should try to log the error inside the addOnFailureListener. Do you get any output?

Comment: Are you sure your `$imageName` is same with the image name in storage??

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my question. Feel free to check it, thanks !

Comment: @MuhammadRioPermana Yes, it is same

Comment: Oh I have solved my problems ! I just noticed that my image file without ".jpg" when I add into the firebase... thanks a lot guys !!